# is __defineGetter__ deprecated in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) from MDN, `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__()` should not be used:

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.
>
> **Deprecated**
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

On the other hand, this notice mentions just the product sites facing the Web, incompatibilities between implementations, and browser support.

It clearly applies to the client-side. So, I wonder if it is also deprecated for server-side use, and what is the best alternative option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) and such, which were never standard, were made obsolete by ECMAScript5 (2009) by `Object.defineProperty`, getter/setter literal syntax in object initializers, and in ECMAScript 2015 ("ES6") by get/set declarations in classes. That syntax is deprecated even in the engines that supported it, regardless of whether the engine is being used in the browser, on a server, or in a non-web application.

Here are examples of the standard syntax. I've included setters in them as well, but of course you'd leave those off for read-only properties.

1. `Object.defineProperty` (ES5+, 2009):

   ```
   Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {
       get: function() {
           return "the value";
       },
       set: function(value) {
           // Do something with value
       }
   });
   ```
2. Getter/setter literal syntax in object initializers (ES5+, 2009):

   ```
   var obj = {
       get name() {
           return "the value";
       },
       set name(value) {
           // Do something with value
       }
   };
   ```

   *(I used `var` in that example to stick to ES5 features, but all major engines have long supported `let` and `const`.)*
3. Getter/setter syntax in classes (ES2015, aka "ES6"):

   ```
   class Example {
       get name() {
           return "the value";
       }
       set name(value) {
           // Do something with value
       }
   }
   ```

Those are all **long**-supported by all major JavaScript engines (including those used by the vast majority of server-side environments [V8 in Node.js and Deno; JavaScriptCore in Bun]).

New code should use these rather than the old never-standard syntax.

Comment: Perhaps [*obviated*](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=define+obviated&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=mSkNVua4Aaru8weC8444) rather than obsoleted.

Comment: @RobG: :-) I actually think "obsoleted" is just fine. After all, if you wanted to have setters/getters prior to them being standardized, and you were using something that supported `__defineGetter__`, then it's what you'd have used. That use is made obsolete by the standard methods when they were added.

Comment: By definition obsolete means that it's no longer supported. Object.__defineGetter__ is still supported by modern JavaScript engines therefore it is not obsolete. It is simply deprecated in favor of Object.defineProperty.

Comment: @PHPGuru - [Obsolete](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obsolete) just means "outdated, old, passé, ancient." It doesn't mean something doesn't exist anymore. (This feature is *also* deprecated, as well as being obsolete.)

Comment: `__defineGetter__` remains in use and is therefore unlikely to be removed from browsers. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__#description): `__defineGetter__() is defined in the spec as "normative optional", which means no implementation is required to implement this. However, all major browsers implement it, and due to its continued usage, it's unlikely to be removed. If a browser implements __defineGetter__(), it also needs to implement the __lookupGetter__(), __lookupSetter__(), and __defineSetter__() methods.`

Comment: @PHPGuru - Yes, I know. I never said otherwise. It's obsolete and deprecated, not *removed*.

Comment: [Obsolete means that it has been removed from browsers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Writing_guidelines/Experimental_deprecated_obsolete#obsolete) `__defineGetter__` is supported by all major browsers. So it sounds like we agree on everything except for semantics.

Comment: @PHPGuru - Thank you for that link, now I know what you meant on the 31st. **Wow** that's an unfortunate way to use "obsolete." I'm glad the more curated version of MDN phased / is phasing it out, it's not in keeping with the standard English meaning. Having thought about it a bit, I'm still happy with "made obsolete" in the above. It's entirely standard, especially in that form. But thank you again for letting me know about MDN's former usage. Happy 2024!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__` and its related methods are deprecated everywhere including Node.js not just in browsers.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__#sect2):

> **This feature is deprecated in favor of defining getters using the object initializer syntax or the Object.defineProperty() API.** This method's behavior is only specified for web compatibility, and is not required to be implemented in any platform. It may not work everywhere.

Despite being deprecated, `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__` still works in all modern browsers, and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__#description) is unlikely to be removed:

> `__defineGetter__()` is defined in the spec as "normative optional", which means no implementation is required to implement this. However, all major browsers implement it, and due to its continued usage, it's unlikely to be removed. If a browser implements `__defineGetter__()`, it also needs to implement the `__lookupGetter__()`, `__lookupSetter__()`, and `__defineSetter__()` methods.

In [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/conformance.html#sec-conformance.normative-optional) `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__` is described as [Normative Optional, Legacy](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.__defineGetter__) which means pretty much what MDN wrote above. From the Spec:

> A conforming implementation of ECMAScript must implement Legacy subclauses, unless they are also marked as Normative Optional. All of the language features and behaviours specified within Legacy subclauses have one or more undesirable characteristics. However, their continued usage in existing applications prevents their removal from this specification. These features are not considered part of the core ECMAScript language. Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours when writing new ECMAScript code.

As of Chrome 5, Firefox 4, and Safari 5.1  (circa 2011) there is `Object.defineProperty` which should be used instead. So the only reason to use `Object.prototype.__defineGetter__` in new code would be if for some reason you had to support browsers older than that, and then you should only do that in old browsers where `Object.defineProperty` was not supported.